# JS SetInterval with dynamic keys not clearing

Tags: javascript, function, key, setinterval, clearinterval

The following code sets an interval. If the function is recalled it is supposed to clear the existing interval first. However it is not. The only theory I have is that the the function variable key is not sufficient for identifying the original interval.

Can you call and clear an interval with a dynamic key?

```
function countdown(key, target, timestamp){
        
    clearInterval(key)
    key = setInterval(function(){
            
        if(timestamp <= 0){
            clearInterval(key)
        }
            
        timestamp = timestamp - 1
        target.text(timestamp)

    }, 1000)
}
```

Activating that interval works

```
$("#somethhing").click(function(){
    countdown("testInterval", $("div.showTimer"), 12000)
})
```

However if `#somethhing` is clicked again it does not clear the interval first. It's as though using `key` does not satisfy the ID for clearing the interval. Is there a way to do this or do all intervals have to be set with clearly defined variables in order to clear them.

Comment: `setInterval()` returns a generated numeric id of the interval. You can not choose it yourself. You have to store the return of `setInterval()`. For instance you can store it in the `dataset` of `target` (`target.dataset.timer = setInterval(..`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you reassign `key`, the new value as returned by setInterval does not change anything. What you need to do is get access to the variable to clear it.

You cannot define variables to clear them yourself. you have to save the id. you can save an object that maps the names you want to those ids and just have the function update that object if you like

Answer (score 1):

To add clarity to the answer from @QuarkNerd ad the comment of @Lain here is the example from the question using their suggestions.

```
function countdown(target, timestamp){
        
    var key = setInterval(function(){
            
        if(timestamp <= 0){
            clearInterval(key)
        }
            
        timestamp = timestamp - 1
        target.text(timestamp)

    }, 1000)
    return key
}

$("#somethhing").click(function(){
    var testInterval
    clearInterval(testInterval)
    testInterval = countdown($("div.showTimer"), 12000)
})
```